# Dynamic order in django-mptt

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I am using a django-mptt package for my comments application and I have following model for this:

```
class Comment(MPTTModel):
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Treść')
    author = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='Autor', blank=False, null=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Komentarz usunięty', default=False,
                                     help_text='Zaznacz, aby usunąć komentarz')

    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default=0, verbose_name='Adres IP')

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name='Typ obiektu')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='ID obiektu')
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
    hotness = models.FloatField(default=0)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, verbose_name='Data dodania')

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Aktualizacja')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ('-hotness', '-created_at')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Komentarz'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Komentarze'

    def __unicode__(self):
        if len(self.content) > 50:
            return self.content[:50] + '...'
        else:
            return self.content
```

I would like to give user possibility to sort comment tree by hotness or creation date. Is it possible to edit `order_insertion_by` field from view to generate 2 types of sorting(by date, by hotness)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution about that?

Comment: I did a few tests with my code example below (python3) and it seems to work - BUT it would be nice if someone else would try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Modified Preorder Tree Traversal` (MPTT) is a way to retrieve a tree structure with one query using left (`lft` in mptt) and right (`rgt`) numbering as shown here http://sitepointstatic.com/graphics/sitepoint_numbering.gif.

Defining more than one order_insertion_by will do the following(according to mptts comments):

```
"""
    Creates a filter which matches suitable right siblings for ``node``,
    where insertion should maintain ordering according to the list of
    fields in ``order_insertion_by``.

    For example, given an ``order_insertion_by`` of
    ``['field1', 'field2', 'field3']``, the resulting filter should
    correspond to the following SQL::

       field1 > %s
       OR (field1 = %s AND field2 > %s)
       OR (field1 = %s AND field2 = %s AND field3 > %s)

"""
```

If I understand it correctly, `order_insertion_by` specifies the ordering of siblings, which represent children (not descendants) of a parent element. If you want two different orders, `lft` and `rgt` would have to change aswell, and thus it is a second tree. This is not included in mptt.

You could still do

```
Comment.objects.all().order_by('-hotness')
```

but you would lose the tree structure. It is generally not possible to maintain the tree structure and order the whole tree by something else, e.g. hotness. Imagine you have the following:

```
Comment1 (hotness 0)
    Comment2 (hotness 2, child of Comment1)
Comment3 (hotness 1)
```

which would result in

```
Comment2
Comment3
Comment1
```

It is ordered, but `Comment2` is not attached to `Comment1`.
If you want to sort using something else than defined by `order_insertion_by` on a sibling-level-basis, to get the following:

```
Comment3
Comment1
    Comment2
```

one might be able to write a new template tag like `{% recursetree objects -hotness %}` that iterates over and re-sorts `children` elements and returns the new tree. It still is one database query - but I cannot estimate the performance hit.

You will have to fork mptt and edit `mptt_tags.py` as follows:

```
class RecurseTreeNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, template_nodes, queryset_var, order_var=None):
        self.template_nodes = template_nodes
        self.queryset_var = queryset_var
        self.order_var = order_var

    def _render_node(self, context, node):
        bits = []
        context.push()

        children = node.get_children()

        if children and self.order_var is not None:
            children = children.order_by(self.order_var)            

        for child in children:
            bits.append(self._render_node(context, child))
        context['node'] = node
        context['children'] = mark_safe(''.join(bits))
        rendered = self.template_nodes.render(context)
        context.pop()
        return rendered

    def render(self, context):
        queryset = self.queryset_var.resolve(context)
        roots = cache_tree_children(queryset)
        bits = [self._render_node(context, node) for node in roots]
        return ''.join(bits)


@register.tag
def recursetree(parser, token):
    bits = token.contents.split()
    if len(bits) < 2:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(_('%s tag requires a queryset') % bits[0])

    queryset_var = template.Variable(bits[1])

    if len(bits) == 3:
        order_var = bits[2]
    else:
        order_var = None

    template_nodes = parser.parse(('endrecursetree',))
    parser.delete_first_token()

    return RecurseTreeNode(template_nodes, queryset_var, order_var)
```